# Open activity from class that extends MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I am dynamically adding rows to a table in my MainActivity from a class that extends MainActivity. In this class that I call FeedRow I assign an onClick listener to a button that was in the layout I used to inflate the row with. When I click the button to load an activity the cat says that the intent is null. I hope you understand my question. Thank you.

```
04-01 23:47:40.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
04-01 23:47:40.282: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3813)
```

Class:

```
public class FeedRow extends MainActivity implements OnClickListener {

String status = "";
Context context
View v;

 FeedRow(Context context, TableLayout table, String status){
// A lot of code to create the row button shown only...

 Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.commentButton);
 button.setOnClickListener(this);

 } 


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// Intent will be null when I try to run
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, CommentActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but your `Activity` should not have a constructor. Secondly, for your `context`, you can simple use `this`, as Activity, somewhere down the line extends `Context`.

Comment: this is a class that adds rows to a table, it only extends main activity

Comment: these rows are displayed in a table in mainactivity, however I can not get an intent to work from my button which is dynamically created

Comment: @Nico89  you have a constructor for a Activity class wrong

Comment: ok, I will not extend main activity, how can I invoke an intent to start an activity from a separate class that is not an activity

Comment: @Nico89 you will need a valid context in any case.

Comment: Did not extend main activity, use context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: @Nico89 your problem is you din't initialize context. Use this a valid context. But constructor is not necessary. yes you need `context.startActivity(intent)` coz startActivity is a method of Activity class